# Query TFS based on value change of a field

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

There is any possibility in TFS UI to query based value changed of a field?
E.g.

Query all work items which have changed *Automation status* field to "Automated" in the past 2 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Automation status` field reference the `System.State` (reference name), then you can try below query: 
[image]

If the filed doesn't reference `System.State`, then we cannot achieve the requirement.

However you can custom a field and apply rules for the field to copy the value of `State Change Date`, something like this :

```
<FieldDefinition name="test" refname="test.date" type="DateTime">
  <WHEN field="Automationstatus.xxx" value="Automated">
    <COPY from="field" field="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate" />
  </WHEN>
  <HELPTEXT>test</HELPTEXT>
</FieldDefinition>
```

Thus when you change `Automation status` to "`Automated`" for a work item, the changed date will be copied to the `test` filed. Then you can use the `test` field to filter the work items in future... but it's not available for current work items.

Comment: Hi Andi, I tried to implement something like this, to populate an Automation Date based on the value changed of Automation Status. We are having some problems, it is populated on other scenarios but this seems to be a way to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no easy way to query on the change times of specific fields in the UI from the work item queries.

If your company has the Analytics Services turned on and available to users, [then you could use Excel's Power Pivot tools to query the cube directly.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sql-reports/?view=tfs-2018)

**NOTE**: The TFS Warehouse and Analytics Cube haven't seen major updates since their introduction in 2010 and are being replaced by the new OData based Analytics Service in Azure Devops.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's a query parameter to satisfy your criteria entirely, but the closest I can come up with is this:

[image]

Comment: That is not working. It is also work items which were only changed in the past 2 days and had automation status = automated before changed date.